# Using DataSet As Data Model in asp.net MVC 4 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dataset

I want to use Data Set as my Model in my mvc 4 project. How to use the model binding with data sets. can any one give me a solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use DataSet Like this -

Controller Action -

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Marks");

    dt.Clear();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "rami";
    dr["Marks"] = "500";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);


    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    return View(ds);
}
```

Index Action -

```
@model System.Data.DataSet

@using System.Data

@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables["Marks"].Rows)
{
    @(row["Name"] + " " + row["Marks"])
}
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how i work with insert and updates with data sets now its give me "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." when i try to save data

Comment: I dont think retrieving data is an easy job. Refer this solved thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375370/datatable-model-bind-in-mvc. Its always better you can convert your datatable to models, and then use it in your CRUD operations.

Comment: It is true, if used as a model it needs a paramaterless constructor. So perhaps a strongly typed dataset or simply inheriting from one for your model would fix the issue.